# Centering 2nd level drop down relative to parent

Tags: html, css

I have a menu that I need to modify. 
I need the drop down part of the menu to be [potentially] centered relative to it's parent.

Yes, the menu sits on the right hand side of the page.

The 2nd level menu items will be displayed horizontally below the 1st level item.

eg.

```
        top level
bottom | level  | items
```

JSFiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/smxA8/

IMPORTANT: Notice that one of the 2nd level items is currently on 2 lines... **needs to be on a single line.**

Note: this is for a CMS. So, there are no fixed widths for any of this. 
Users can add to the menu at any level without modifying the css.

Comment: So, you want it to be centered on its parent, unless it has to move over because it is too close to the edge?

Comment: Would you be open to javascript solutions?

Comment: "So, you want it to be centered on its parent, unless it has to move over because it is too close to the edge?"- YES!

yes, I guess i'd be open to JS solutions. Would prefer css but might be easier with JS...

Comment: These kinds of menus are especially difficult when you're trying to fit an unlimited amount of content in a limited amount of space. What kind of behavior would you want if the submenu is longer than the container?

Comment: @Wex: The 2nd level menu would then have to be displayed on 2 lines. (similar to what is currently happening under the resources tab in JS Fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/smxA8/)

Remember that the top level would be variable in size. So, you can't set a fixed width for the 1st or 2nd levels.
There will however be a max width for the first level of about 700px (distance before the menu hits the logo on the other side of the page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, there is no clean way to do that just using CSS. Because you need to have child's width or use center aligns. So my suggestion is go for having some JS code.

Edition: Using JS which is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/Zqypz/